# Resources on managing, phasing, composing monads (in Scala or Haskell)

Tags: scala, haskell, monads

I am looking for resources discussing good practice for composing monads.  My most pressing problem is that I'm writing a system that is making use of a series of state monads over different state types, and it seems as if the best way to handle this situation is to just create one big product type (perhaps prettied up as a record/class) encompassing all the components I'm interested in even though phase 1 is not interested in component B, and phase 2 is only interested in component A.1.

I'd appreciate pointers to nice discussions of alternatives when writing code in this sort of area.  My own code-base is in Scala, but I'm happy to read discussions about the same issues in Haskell.

Comment: My 0.02$ is that a product type would be much easier to manage in Haskell than stacking multiple `StateT` transformers.  I'd use a record since you can pretty easily update one field, and GHC optimizes that pretty well (AFAIK).  Then you can write a `getStateName` and `putStateName` for each field of the record that updates each individual field (if you really wanted to get fancy, you could write some TH for it).  I can't comment on Scala though.

Comment: `Control.Lens.Zoom` is designed exactly to allow you to use lenses to restrict what parts of the state in your `State` monad you want to operate on.

Comment: Whacking everything into one state type also seems to wreck modularity.

Comment: @MichaelNorrish See my answer for one (at least partial) solution to maintaining modularity while using the whacked together global state space solution.

Comment: I am tempted to answer: _just don't use state monads_.  There are a few cases where you need all the power that (explicit) state monads deliver and don't need any of the things they forbid, but in my experience there's almost always a better way (at least in Scala).  But you haven't described the problem in enough detail for me to offer any alternatives.

Comment: I'm implementing a parser for terms/formulas, followed by unification over type variables.  The parser needs state to represent the names that are or aren't in scope (so that they pick up the same type variables), and the unification needs to be able to generate fresh tyvars, and to maintain the current type substitution.

Answer (score 8):

It's a bit challenging to use stacks of `StateT` because it becomes confusing as to which layer you're talking to when you write `get` or `put`. If you use an explicit stack in `transformers` style then you have to use a bunch of `lift`s and if you use the class-based method of `mtl` you get stuck entirely.

```
-- using transformers explicit stack style
type Z a = StateT Int (StateT String IO) a

go :: Z ()
go = do int <- get
        str <- lift get
        replicateM int (liftIO $ putStrLn str)
```

We might want to avoid that mess with an explicit product type of states. Since we end up with functions from our product state to each individual component it's easy to `get` into those individual components using `gets`

```
data ZState = ZState { int :: Int, str :: String }
type Z a = StateT ZState IO a

go :: Z ()
go = do i <- gets int
        s <- gets str
        replicateM i (liftIO $ putStrLn s)
```

But this might be considered ugly still for two reasons: (1) `put` and modification in general doesn't have anywhere nearly as nice a story and (2) we can't easily look at the type of a function which *only* impacts, say, the `int` state and know that it doesn't touch `str`. We'd much prefer to maintain that type-ensured modularity.

If you're `lens`-savvy there's a solution called [`zoom`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.0.4/docs/Control-Lens-Zoom.html#v%3azoom)

```
-- the real type is MUCH more general
zoom :: Lens' mother child -> StateT child m a -> StateT mother m a
```

which "lifts" a stateful computation on a subpart of some larger state space up to the entire state space. Or, pragmatically, we use it like this:

```
data ZState = ZState { _int :: Int, _str :: String }
makeLenses ''ZState

type Z = StateT ZState IO a

inc :: MonadState Int m => m ()
inc = modify (+1)

yell :: MonadState String m => m ()
yell = modify (map toUpper)

go :: Z ()
go = do zoom int $ do inc
                      inc
                      inc
        zoom str yell
        i <- use int
        s <- use str
        replicateM i (liftIO $ putStrLn s)
```

And now most of the problems should have vanished—we can `zoom` in to isolate stateful operations which only depend upon a subset of the total state like `inc` and `yell` and determine their isolation in their type. We also can still `get` inner state components using `use`.

More than this, `zoom` can be used to `zoom` in on state buried deep inside various tranformer stacks. The fully general type works just fine in a situation like this

```
type Z a = EitherT String (ListT (StateT ZState IO)) a

>>> :t zoom int :: EitherT String (ListT (StateT Int IO)) a -> Z a
zoom int :: EitherT String (ListT (StateT Int IO)) a -> Z a
```

But while this is really nice, the fully general `zoom` requires some heavy trickery and you can only zoom over some transformer layers. (It's today heavily unclear to me how you add that functionality to your own layer, though presumably it's possible.)

Comment: If you ever need help implementing `zoom` for your own transformer just ask me, although in general I find it is simpler to implement `MFunctor` and just `hoist` the `zoom` (since it is a monad morphism).

Comment: I'll hit you up about that at some point: I'm never sure of how the Zoomed types play in.

Comment: Zooms/lenses certainly sound like the 'right' solution, if possible.  Are there any nice writeups/descriptions for both Lens (I haven't found anything great to date), and even `StateT`?

Comment: I don't know if there's anything great. I've tried to write a few, but `lens` is new, large, and requires a bit of a conceptual shift. I highly suggest looking at the various lens tutorials on FP Complete (I'll plug my own https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/a-little-lens-starter-tutorial).

Comment: `StateT` should be covered in depth in any monad transformer tutorial. It's basically one of the three poster children of the transformer concept.